# Displaying Kriging Interpolation 3D in ArcScene?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, geotiff-tiff, arcscene, kriging

I am trying to display my kriging.tiff interpolation raster in 3d within ArcScene. The reason to do this would be to visually see where the high values and low values are for my analysis. This would be similar to how DEM data is displayed in 3D for easier viewing and analysis.

I have tried using the 'raster to TIN' tool on the kriging raster but my image is still flat even though it says the base heights should be floating on a custom surface.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Assuming you are on the `Layer Properties | Base Heights` tab, you may be able to enhance the height by changing `Elevation from features | Factor to convert layer elevation values to scene units:`. Maybe x5 or x10 would do?

Comment: The problem is that it isn't even displaying the height at all. All changing those values did was move the whole thing up or down, still flat. :(

I've edited my post and uploaded a screen capture

Comment: In my case, it goes up or down when I change `Layer offset` value. Isn't it what you have tried?

Comment: As a separate note, you can display your kriging.tiff as 3D layer without converting to TIN.

Comment: It would be great to simply display it without converting to TIN. I have tried doing so with my kriging layer and still nothing, just flat

Comment: In my experience it looks *3D-like* when top and bottom values ranges over 1000. As your data range is about 20, you may need to give `Factor to convert` (next to `custom`) 20 or even up to 50.0, potentially. You have 1.0 now.

Comment: I wish ArcScene showed the height stretched to min/max by default. I am glad it worked out. :)

Answer (score 1):

In order to show it in 3D, you need to have X,Y, and Z values enabled in the kriging feature.

Did you use the kriging tool in Spatial Analyst, Geostatistical Analyst, or 3D Analyst?

My suggestions:

1. Do all the kriging experimentation in Geostatistical Analyst so you can check assumptions and fit a couple models first.
2. Once you know your parameters, write them down and use the Kriging tool in the 3D analyst toolbox. You may need to convert whatever your analysis field is into a 3D-enabled field first (Feature to 3D by Attribute I think).

That way the output has X, Y, and Z values so when you bring it into ArcScene it can read it in 3D correctly. I have done exactly this process before, just for an IDW (and therefore deterministic) interpolation, so YMMV.